# CUDA (from C++) Hyperbolic Trig Functions Calculate Different Results in Different Locations

Tags: cuda

I'm running into an odd issue with a simulation I wrote.  I recently restructured my code to make things cleaner and more organized.  Basically (among other things) I moved (basically copy-pasted) the CUDA function in question to another file.  This function uses `asinh` to compute something, as well as `sinh` and `cosh`.  What I've noticed is that before the move, the function produced expected results consistent with hand calculated values (in excel).  After the move, the hyperbolic functions are fed the same inputs, yet the results are significantly different (up to 10% in `asinh`, 0.5% in `sinh`).  This effectively breaks my simulation.  I am confident in the rest of the function.

EDIT:
Upon further testing, I've found hard-coding values for the angle (lambdaDegrees) in question - namely `double x{ asinh(sqrt(3.0) * sin(lambdaDegrees * 3.1415927 / 180.0)) };` - produces the (good) expected results.  Measuring the angle before and after the equation is executed, the angle is unchanged, yet without hard-coding the value, it produces the wrong results.  The weirdest part is simply adding another diagnostic printf function caused the function to produce yet another (wrong) result.  I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the way I've set up a callback function on the GPU...maybe multiple threads using the function at the same time leading to some (consistent) undefined behavior?

After a bit of screwing around with the code, I reproduced the error.  Expected value of x within getSAtLambda (the printf statement) is 1.268...  Result is 1.768...  Let me know what you think.

main.cu

```
//CUDA includes
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuda_profiler_api.h"

typedef double(*callbackFcn)(double*, int, double, double, int);

//on GPU global variables
extern __device__ double*     fieldConstArray_GPU;
extern __device__ int         arraySize_GPU;
extern __device__ callbackFcn callback_GPU;

__host__ __device__ double BFieldAtS(double* consts, int arrayLength, double s, double simtime, int thdInd);
__host__ __device__ double gradBAtS(double* consts, int arrayLength, double s, double simtime, int thdInd);
__global__ void setupEnvironmentGPU(double* constArrayPtr);

__global__ void execute()
{
    int thdInd{ blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x };
    callback_GPU(fieldConstArray_GPU, arraySize_GPU, (thdInd == 31487) ? 1233005.097 : ((115200 - thdInd) / 50000.0 * 6.371e6), 0.0, thdInd ); //3rd argument are example values
}

void setupEnvironment()
{// consts: [ B0, ILATDeg, L, L_norm, s_max ]
    double fieldConstArray_h[]{ 3.12e-5, 72.0, 66717978.17, 10.47213595, 85670894.1 };
    double* fieldConstants_d{ nullptr };

    cudaMalloc((void **)&fieldConstants_d, 5 * sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(fieldConstants_d, fieldConstArray_h, 5 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    setupEnvironmentGPU <<< 1, 1 >>> (fieldConstants_d);
}

int main()
{
    setupEnvironment();
    int loops{ 0 };

    while (loops < 3)
    {
        execute <<< 115200 / 256, 256 >>> ();
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        loops++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

otherfunctions.cu

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

//CUDA includes
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuda_profiler_api.h"

typedef double(*callbackFcn)(double*, int, double, double, int);

__device__ double*     fieldConstArray_GPU{ nullptr };
__device__ int         arraySize_GPU{ 7 };
__device__ callbackFcn callback_GPU{ nullptr };

__host__ __device__ double getSAtLambda(double* consts, int arrayLength, double lambdaDegrees, double simtime, int thdInd)
{//returns s in units of L
    double x{ asinh(sqrt(3.0) * sin(lambdaDegrees * 3.1415927 / 180.0)) };

    if (simtime == 0.0 && thdInd == 31487) { printf("\n\ngetSAtLambda: %f, %f\n\n", lambdaDegrees, x); }

    return (0.5 * consts[2] / sqrt(3.0)) * (x + sinh(x) * cosh(x));
}

__host__ __device__ double getLambdaAtS(double* consts, int arrayLength, double s, double simtime, int thdInd)
{// consts: [ B0, ILATDeg, L, L_norm, s_max, ds, errorTolerance ]
    double lambda_tmp{ (-consts[1] / consts[4]) * s + consts[1] }; //-ILAT / s_max * s + ILAT
    double s_tmp{ consts[4] - getSAtLambda(consts, arrayLength, lambda_tmp, simtime, thdInd) };
    double dlambda{ 1.0 };
    bool   over{ 0 };

    while (abs((s_tmp - s) / s) > 1e-4) //errorTolerance
    {
        while (1)
        {
            over = (s_tmp >= s);
            if (over)
            {
                lambda_tmp += dlambda;
                s_tmp = consts[4] - getSAtLambda(consts, arrayLength, lambda_tmp, simtime, 0);
                if (s_tmp < s)
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                lambda_tmp -= dlambda;
                s_tmp = consts[4] - getSAtLambda(consts, arrayLength, lambda_tmp, simtime, 0);
                if (s_tmp >= s)
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (dlambda < 1e-4 / 100.0) //errorTolerance
            break;
        dlambda /= 5.0; //through trial and error, this reduces the number of calculations usually (compared with 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 10)
    }

    return lambda_tmp;
}

__host__ __device__ double BFieldAtS(double* consts, int arrayLength, double s, double simtime, int thdInd)
{// consts: [ B0, ILATDeg, L, L_norm, s_max, ds, errorTolerance ]
    double lambda_deg{ getLambdaAtS(consts, arrayLength, s, simtime, thdInd) };
    double lambda_rad{ lambda_deg * 3.1415927 / 180.0 };
    double rnorm{ consts[3] * pow(cos(lambda_rad), 2) };

    return -consts[0] / pow(rnorm, 3) * sqrt(1.0 + 3 * pow(sin(lambda_rad), 2));
}

__host__ __device__ double gradBAtS(double* consts, int arrayLength, double s, double simtime, int thdInd)
{
    return (BFieldAtS(consts, arrayLength, s + consts[5], simtime, thdInd) - BFieldAtS(consts, arrayLength, s - consts[5], simtime, thdInd)) / (2 * consts[5]);
}

__global__ void setupEnvironmentGPU(double* constArrayPtr)
{
    callback_GPU = gradBAtS; //sets pointer to callback function
    arraySize_GPU = 7;
    fieldConstArray_GPU = constArrayPtr;
}
```

Comment: [mcve] or it hasen't happened... What values have you fed in, what were the results?

Comment: I'm going to have to double back.  I'm seeing now that the result I'm getting is bigger than the max value allowed by equation below.  I'll work on this.  In the mean time, are you aware of any headers that affect accuracy?  For example, I read that in old versions of CUDA, only floats were supported, and later on with newer architectures, support for doubles was added.  Although it wouldn't add up to a 10% error, perhaps this is involved.  The equation calculated is: asinh(sqrt(3.0) * sin(ANGLE)).  I've verified that the angle is the same, yet the results are different from a previous commit.

Comment: Your computation uses double precision arithmetic, yet in the expression `sin(lambdaDegrees * 3.1415927 / 180.0))` you use a low-precision approximation to π, barely accurate to single precision. That does not seem to make sense. It would be best to use `sinpi` here to avoid explicit use of an explicit π-constant and provide maximum accuracy. You wouldn't want to square and cube variables by using `pow()`, use multiplies instead.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks.  That's a good point.  Those will be good changes to make.  Although, nonetheless, if you put those functions into one file as is, they compute a different result (accurate) than when the files are split (as above, inaccurate results).  Any thoughts on why that might be?  The pi estimate is simply contrived for this example.

Comment: @tera If I've satisfied the requirement, would you consider undoing your down vote?  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your question.

Comment: @tera ok nevermind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A summary of my findings:

**On Cuda 8.0:**

Correct results are produced when the code above:

1. Is compiled as debug instead of release (except for -O1)
2. When a trig identity of asinh is used instead of the actual asinh function
3. When the argument for asinh is hardcoded
4. With -O1 instead of -O2 for both release and debug
5. (Paradoxically) When the function getSAtLambda is called directly instead of through a function pointer

Incorrect results are produced for asinh(x) when:

1. Compiled as release with -O2 with a non-hardcoded value through a function pointer

**Updating to CUDA 9.1 fixed the issue.**

Comment: [This cross posting on the Nvidia forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1029300/cuda-programming-and-performance/cuda-hyperbolic-trig-functions-calculate-different-results-in-different-locations/1) has more details about how the issue was resolved.